# Multinomial additive property

Tags: st.statistics

I am studying multinomial distribution and found additive property.

But, the text gives me concise explanation.

> Suppose we focus on one particular category j, then you can easily show that Xj ∼ Bin(n, pj).
> Note that X1, · · · , Xk are not independent due to the constraint that X1 + X2 + · · · + Xk = n.
> Also, for any Xi and Xj , you can easily show that Xi + Xj ∼ Bin(n, pi + pj).

Can I get some self-study books for multinomial additive property?

Comment: I think there will be no book on the "multinomial additive property". If I understand your intention correctly its simply a consequence of the definition of the multinomial distribution, as found f.i. in Wikipedia, and the fact that you can join two or more posible outcomes to one. Of course you have to add the corresponding probabilities at the final part of your citation.

Comment: @DieterKadelka Thank you :)